# I want to pass data from javascript code to flask server

Tags: javascript, python, html, json, flask

I have a problem concerning the sending of data from the javascript code in html template and their reception on my flask server
I want to send the geolocation coordinates (latitude and longitude), I can get them using the javascript but I don't know how to send these latitude and longitude to my flask server.
thank you in advance for your help

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to get your coordinates.</p>

<button onclick="getLocation()">Try It</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var x = document.getElementById("demo");

function getLocation() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
  } else { 
    x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
  }
}

function showPosition(position) {
  x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
  "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where is your flask code? What's the endpoint to receive the information?

Comment: you have to use `AJAX`/`XHR` to send it to some URL in your Flask and it gets it as any other request from browser. You can also learn `jQuery` and `$.ajax()`. You can also use Google to find some similar question on Stackoverflow and learn from answers. As I remember few months ago I answered for the same problem and you should find many similar answers. maybe even few days ago was question about sending POST with form data using JavaScript.

Comment: Make a `POST` request using `fetch()`.

Answer (score 2):

It is minimal example which use [jQuery.getJSON()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) to send request to url /ajax?x=...&y=... and receive answer in `JSON` format.

In `jQuery` documentation you can find other methods to send `AJAX`.

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, render_template_string

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template_string('''
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type=text/javascript>
$(function() {
  $("a#sender").bind("click", function() {
    $.getJSON(
      "{{ url_for('ajax') }}",  // url /ajax
      {"x": 123, "y": 789},     // data (send to server)
      function(data) {          // callback executed when get answer
        console.log(data);      // data (received from server)
        window.alert(data["x"] + ',' + data["y"]);
      });
    return false;  // stop <a> to send normal request
  });
});
</script>
<form>
    <a href="#" id="sender"><button>Send AJAX</button></a>
</form>
''')

@app.route('/ajax')
def ajax():
    print("Hello AJAX")
    # get data from url /ajax?x=...&y=...
    x = request.args.get('x', 0)
    y = request.args.get('y', 0)
    print('x:', x)
    print('y:', y)
    # send answer as JSON
    return jsonify({'x': x, 'y': y})

if __name__ == "__main__":
    #app.run(debug=True)
    app.run()
```

---

**EDIT:** I added @roganjosh suggestions: `render_template_string(...)` and `url_for('ajax')`

Comment: I would suggest that, since you gave a URL endpoint, you use `url: "{{ url_for('ajax') }}",` in your example to make it internally consistent

Comment: I've seen multiple questions where just putting `/ajax` causes issues, particularly around blueprints

Comment: @roganjosh I tried to create minimal example without any other extension - even without `url_for`

Comment: ugh, that's my bad. I was thinking too much about having `render_template` and invoking jinja2 but you're correct. Sorry.

Comment: @roganjosh if you have ideas how to make this answer better then maybe create new answer - with more examples, more comments and explanations, etc. It can be also useful - compare minimal version with more secure.

Comment: I could do that, but there's only minimal things I would change so I would rather improve the answer you've already given than duplicate 90% of the content. Instead of just `return`ing the string, you can use `return render_template_string(...)` and switch to `url_for`. That's all my answer would change

Comment: @roganjosh or maybe you could create example without jQuery - only pure JavaScript. It seems OP doesn't use jQuery in question.

Comment: @roganjosh I added your suggestions to answer.